# Corner clamps, standards/quality

Tags: clamps

I am looking for corner clamps. One type I have come across consists of an L-shaped piece of metal or plastic and then we use those along with some other bits to create a corner clamp. The problem is that, all of them have some negative reviews where a person says that the clamps they got are not exactly square and/or not even square with each other (if they bought set of 4).

Is there some international standard that corner clamp must comply with that I can look for to be sure that it has been manufactured to a high standard and I can be sure that it will definitely be square?

Comment: This might be something that you could build yourself and be much more satisfied with the outcome than you'd have buying cheap corner clamps that may or may not be square. A quick google search for "build corner clamps" provides a pretty extensive list of YouTube videos for making your own corner clamps and many of those also provide free plans.

Comment: I've never seen a clamp marked BS 939 or DIN 875-1. If you have money and desire, either go to Woodpeckers (set of 4 for $230usd, tolerance +/-.0255 degrees), or buy the aluminum ones off amazon or wherever, then bring them to a small machine shop to be made near perfect (which, depending on volume/etc, might get you to the woodpeckers price in the first place).

Comment: I will have a look on youtube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some international standard that corner clamp must comply with that I can look for to be sure that it has been manufactured to a high standard and I can be sure that it will definitely be square?

None that I'm aware of. Woodworking tools normally don't need to be so perfectly precise that they require calibration or certification.

Unless you're doing a lot of framing or box making, you probably don't need dedicated corner clamps at all. Just cut a block of wood at 90° and use regular clamps to clamp your frame, box, cabinet sides, etc. to the block.

There's an easy way to check whether the corner of the block is square or not: line one side of the block (let's call it side A) up on an edge that you know to be straight, such as the edge of a sheet of paper. Use a sharp pencil to draw a line along the adjacent side of the block (side B), i.e. the one that's perpendicular to the paper edge. Next, flip your block over so that side B is again on the line you drew and side A is again exactly lined up along the edge of the paper. Trace side B with the pencil again. If the two lines line up exactly, the corner is 90°; if they diverge, then the corner isn't exactly 90º.